# How can I place a button under the composable screen correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, composable

How can I place a button under the `AnimatedScreen`?
At the moment, the button is hidden and it is not visible.
Shouldn't the elements in column be arranged sequentially, or is it a matter of the parameter `fillMaxSize` in `AnimatedScreen`?

```
Surface {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        AnimatedScreen(Modifier, rawId = R.raw.onboarding)
        Button(onClick = onContinueClicked) {
            Text(stringResource(R.string.continue_text))
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code of my AnimatedScreen:

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    rawId: Int
) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val compositionResult: LottieCompositionResult = rememberLottieComposition(
            spec = LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(rawId)
        )
        ScreenAnimation(compositionResult = compositionResult)
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenAnimation(compositionResult: LottieCompositionResult) {

    val progress by animateLottieCompositionAsState(composition = compositionResult.value)

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = compositionResult.value,
        progress = progress,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `weight` modifier to `AnimatedScreen` composable:

```
    Column(
       //..
    ) {
        AnimatedScreen(Modifier.weight(1f, false))
        Button(onClick = {  }) { }
    }
```